# Problem with Rider IDE. Was digging into the settings and hid the menu

Tags: jetbrains-ide, rider

The menu with the code files and the compiler window on the right disappeared.

[image]

Does anyone knows if it's possible to reset everything to factory settings so that everything comes back in advance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To restore settings to default, see https://www.jetbrains.com/help/rider/Reset_Settings.html#restore-defaults.

Data copied from that location:

1. Press Shift twice and type Restore default settings.
2. In the confirmation popup that opens, click Restore and Restart. The IDE will be restarted with the default configuration.

Best of luck solving your problem.